# How would one scan the poem in Boromir's dream?

Tags: poetry, meter

Tolkien's *The Fellowship of the Ring* contains this short poem, heard by Boromir in a dream and related to the Council of Elrond:

> Seek for the Sword that was broken;
>    In Imladris it
> dwells;
>  There shall be counsels taken
>    Stronger
> than Morgul-spells.
>  There shall be shown a token
>   That Doom is near at hand,
>  For Isildur's Bane shall
> waken,
>    And the Halfling forth shall stand.

I was wondering how one would scan this. I am tempted to call this trochaic trimeter, by ignoring the unstressed syllables at the start of any line and recognizing a caesura at the end of the even-numbered lines:

```
 /    x   x    /    x    x   /  x
Seek for the Sword that was broken;
  (x) / x /   x    /     || 
  In Imladris it dwells;
   /    x    x  /   x   /  x
There shall be counsels taken
    /   x   x    /  x   /     ||
  Stronger than Morgul-spells
 /      x   x   /    x  / x
There shall be shown a token
   (x)  /   x   /   x   /    ||
  That Doom is near at hand,
(x) (x)  /   x     /     x    / x
For I - sil-dur's Bane shall waken,
  (x) (x)  /   x    /     x     /     ||
  And the Halfling forth shall stand.
```

This requires replacing quite a few trochees with dactyls, though with far fewer substitutions than if I treated this as dactylic trimeter and tried to explain away the trochees. I'm also ignoring line-initial unstressed syllables; trying to account for them in iambs or anapaests leads to a jumble of different meters with no discernible pattern.

Comment: The question seems more suited to English Literature Stack Exchange, so I vote to close it. But I also note that someone else voted it down with no explanation or help to the questioner. I deplore such useless and mute negativity and have compensated.

Comment: I wasn't really sure which site was more appropriate; I chose this one because I thought my question was about the mechanics of the English language used to construct the poem, rather than the content of the poem itself. (The question itself came up as a result of [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/276192/how-to-pronounce-elanor#comment761631_276200).)

Comment: I would say this poem is in *dolnik* meter (this is a word borrowed from Russian to describe a meter that is quite common in English folk songs and poems, but doesn't appear to have a name in English). The rules for dolnik meter is that within each line, there should be either one or two syllables between stressed ones.

Comment: For example, the folk song *Scarborough Fair* (sung by Simon and Garfunkel, but they didn't write it) is in *dolnik* meter: **Tell** her to **find** me an **ac**re of **land**, //
**Pars**ley, **sage,** rose**mar**y and **thyme**, //
Be**tween** the salt **wat**er **and** the sea **strands**, //
**Then** she'll **be** a **true** love of **mine.**

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks, I'd never heard that term before.

Comment: There may be experts over on Literature. ELU would tend to look more at the strange orderings within clauses.

Comment: Now that this question has been reopened, I'm converting my comments into an answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I still believe it's more appropriately asked and answered on Literature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this poem is in dolnik meter (this is a word borrowed from Russian to describe a meter that is quite common in English folk songs and poems, but doesn't appear to have a name in English). The rules for dolnik meter is that within each line, there should be either one or two syllables between stressed ones.

For example, the folk song Scarborough Fair (sung by Simon and Garfunkel, but they didn't write it) is in dolnik meter:

> **Tell** her to **find** me an **ac**re of **land,**
> **Par**sley, **sage,** rose**mar**y and **thyme,**
> Be**tween** the salt **wa**ter **and** the sea **strands,**
> **Then** she'll **be** a **true** love of **mine.**

If you treat your poem as being in dolnik meter, there is only one way to scan the second line, because you need three stressed syllables:

> In **Im**la**dris** it **dwells**.

If Imladris were accented on the second syllable, it wouldn't be possible to scan it in *dolnik* meter.

Thomas Hardy's poem *The Oxen* see [this lit.SE question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/should-there-be-a-trochee-in-the-second-to-last-line-of-thomas-hardys-the-oxen) can also be scanned in *dolnik* meter. This is not the scansion that the website linked to in the question gives. However, the majority of the readings of the poem on YouTube seem to use the dolnik meter. For example, [this one](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/53215/the-oxen-56d232503c32d).

One side note: It's not entirely clear whether the concept of feet makes sense for *dolniks*. You can assume that all feet start with a stressed syllable (as Gerard Manley Hopkins did in his metrical system of *sprung rhythm*, which was based on the meters of English folk songs and folk poetry, which have less regular meters than classical English poetry, and many of which are in *dolnik* meter). But then the entire concept of feet is more or less redundant.

Comment: The Paul Simon song is in triplets, so there are rests that are not indicated in the mere textual representation of the lyrics.  Example, using an apostrophe to show a rest and extending syllables with hyphens:   / ' Parsley / sa-age rose / mary and / ti-i-ime / This is why scansion in poetry is often very different from that in music.

Comment: How does this differ metrically from the four-beat lines of Norse and English alliterative verse, which can vary in syllable count but not in beats? *Thus Arthur abode on the ebb riding, /
At his land he looked and longed sorely / 
on the grass again there green swaying, / 
to walk at his will, while the world lasted; / the sweet to savour of salt mingled /
with wine-scented waft of clover /
over sunlit turf seaward leaning, /
in kindly Christendom the clear ringing /
of bells to hear on the breeze swaying, / a king of peace kingdom wielding / in a holy realm beside heaven’s gateway.*

Comment: @tchrist: English alliterative verse doesn't have the requirement of either one or two syllables between stressed syllables. From *Piers Plowman* "And as I **lay** and **len**ide,
And **lok**ed on the **wat**res,
I **slom**bred into a **slep**yng,
It **swey**ed so **mer**ye." For example, there are four syllables between the stresses in *I slombred into a slepying*.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't bumped into the "dolnik" form before, and wasn't aware of that constraint.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, the traditional classification is to lump everything that isn't iambic, trochaic, anapestic, or dactylic in the category of *accentual verse*.  But there are different meters in this category (and I believe that most of them still don't have names).

Comment: @Robusto: For an example of *dolnik* meter which was not originally set to music, consider: **Hump**ty **Dump**ty **sat** on a **wall.** //
**Hump**ty **Dump**ty **had** a great **fall.** //
**All** the king’s **hors**es and **all** the king’s **men,** //
**Could**n’t put **Hump**ty to**geth**er a**gain.**

Comment: @Robusto: But I also expect the  poets who introduced the *dolnik*  to formal English poetry (Coleridge? Tennyson? Hardy?) drew their inspiration not only from nursery rhymes and folk poems, but also from song lyrics.

Comment: @PeterShor: Well, consider that we don't really know what rhymes were sung and which weren't. But the scansion would indicate that "Humpty Dumpty" would be pronounced with a with a dactylic duration, like a triplet, with two beats on Hump/Dump and one each on the tail, so that they were measured the same  as "All-the-king's horses-and / All-the-king's men - - / Couldn't-put Humpty-to gether-a gain."

Answer (score 3):

The example follows the meter of Kipling's "The Law of the Jungle" and that is anapestic hexameter. The line ***In Imladris it dwells*** requires a strange emphasis.

> Now this is the Law of the Jungle — as old and as true as the sky;
>
> And the Wolf that shall keep it may prosper, but the Wolf that shall break it must die.
>
> As the creeper that girdles the tree-trunk, the Law runneth forward and back —
>
> For the strength of the Pack is the Wolf, and the strength of the Wolf is the Pack.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question.  There is a great deal of 'resolution' in it, as there was in some ancient Greek metres: that is, a single stressed syllable could be 'resolved' into two unstressed syllables and, in some cases, an unstressed syllable could be stressed instead of unstressed (especially, in Aristophanes' comedies, which, being comic, could begin with something like "I am very al**armed**...", where a pair of iambs have been resolved from simple 'short-long-short-long' into five shorts and a long!). An ancient iambic trimetre consisted of three **pairs of** iambs:  an iamb consisted of short-or-long, long, short, long, where the long was thought of as twice a short syllable.  So if the comic genius wanted, he could take the long option of the first syllable *and then resolve that into two shorts*, resolve the second normally long syllable into two more shorts, making four shorts  in succession; then treat the second half of the iamb as a conventional short-long.  So the single inambic foot turns from four syllables to six! So the iambic line might be:

I am very a**larmed** to **see** you **walk**ing **in** the **road**.

This would have been an iambic trimetre, even though it ended up being 'resolved' from a total 12 syllables to 14.

It is probably better to think of the verses as having a movement than a strict metre.

The Boromir poem though not strictly metred, however, does have a structure and a *movement*.  There are *dactyls* (long-short-short), one *anapaest* (short-short-long), at the start of line 7), as well as both iambs (short-long) and trochees (long-short).

It consists of two pairs couplets, rhyming ABAB.  Each line can be understood as having three 'beats' (I have called them 'feet', the conventional term used in classical scholarship).  So the way I should read it would be:-

**Seek** for the / **sword** that was / **bro**ken

**In** Im/**lad**ris it /**dwells.**

**There** shall be / **coun**sels / **tak**en

**Strong**er than /**Mor**gan / **spells**

**There** shall be / **shown** a / **tok**en

That **doom** / is **near** / at **hand**

For Is**il**/dur's **bane** shall **wak**en,

And the **half**/ ling **forth** / shall **stand**.

I can think of alternative interpretations which could work also, but this seems to me to be the underlying rhythm.  You could call it a Tolkenian.  Three beats a line is, I think, a real pattern, as is the rhyme scheme.

---

Comment: Would you put stress on *in* if the line was *In Alaska it dwells*? That seems like a rather strange scansion to me.

Comment: @Peter shor  That's a fair question.  I have two answers.  First, if the 'poem' is actually a song, then the music (which I don't think was written for it) would tell.  Taking the sentence with your substitution on its own, you are right:  I get two anapaests with the stresses on the third and sixth syllables.   But (and this sounds rather subjective) there is something rhythmically awkward following the first line with only two stresses.  I cannot explain this in the space left to me without overrunning the limit.

Comment: @ Peer Shor:  CONTINUED ... All I can say, is that if I now say the second line with "In aLASka it DWELLS" I feel myself mentally teetering over the precipice of a missing foot.  As I say, this is a subjective argument.  But I think it should be 'spondee - dactyl - stressed monosyllable.  The latter, if I had to be technical, would then involve 'catalexis' (omission) of a final unstressed syllable for a final

Answer (score 0):

There is a (possible) mistake in the scansion of the second line as given in the question:

> In **Im**lad**ris** it **dwells**

According to the rules for stress in the Elvish languages given in appendix E of *The Return of the King*, this should be scanned:

> In Im**lad**ris it **dwells**

This is the relevant passage from appendix E (emphasis mine):

> The position of the ‘accent’ or stress is not marked, since in the Eldarin languages concerned its place is determined by the form of the word. In words of two syllables it falls in practically all cases on the first syllable. **In longer words it falls on the last syllable but one**, where that contains a long vowel, a diphthong, or **a vowel followed by two (or more) consonants**. Where the last syllable but one contains (as often) a short vowel followed by only one (or no) consonant, the stress falls on the syllable before it, the third from the end.
>
> <sub>J. R. R. Tolkien (1955). [*The Return of the King*, p. 394](https://archive.org/details/returnofking0000jrrt_k3d3/page/394/mode/2up). London: George Allen and Unwin.</sub>

This causes some difficulty for the scansion, because all the other lines have three stresses, but this line only seems to have two. There are a couple of ways to resolve the problem:

1. Add a third stressed syllable by stressing “In”, as in [Tuffy’s answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/608681/2175).
2. Treat “Imladris” as an exception to the rules in appendix E. We can imagine that it is pronounced as if it is still two separate words, “imlad” (valley, dell) and “riss” (cleft, riven), though if this were intended by Tolkien I would have expected the name to be spelled with a hyphen, “Imlad-ris” (compare “Gil-galad”). Perhaps Tolkien failed to keep his own rules in mind when composing the poem, or perhaps the poem predated the rules.